# Live preview and HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Well I have the live preview of text going using jQuery.

http://jsbin.com/ezuta4

But is there a way where I can put in HTML tags and the HTML won't show but effects the text? Like typing `<h1>` and the tags turn into headings?

So far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#text').keypress(function() {
  $('#live').text($(this).val());
  });
}); // end jQuery 
​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. This won't escape what you type. Also use `.keyup()` instead of `.keypress()`, or else the last character you press won't show until you press something else, the event will happen before the character is rendered.

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    $('#live').html($(this).val());
});
```

**jQuery reference**

- [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
- [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: Great answer! And I was wondering why it was doing that, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

`text()` will parse anything you enter as literal characters. To allow HTML code, use

```
  $('#live').html($(this).val());
```

http://jsbin.com/ezuta4/2

Answer (score 1):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of .text()